# Binning and counting into vector

Tags: r, binning

so I have to make a function that does binning and counts the different breaks. So what I have for now is:

```
 binfunc <- function(numbers, breaks) {
  .bincode(numbers, breaks, right = TRUE, include.lowest = FALSE)
}
```

The output for an example vector would be:

```
numbers1 <- c(20, 70, 14, 30)
breaks1 <- c(youth = 18, adult = 40, elder = Inf)
binfunc(numbers1, breaks1)

[1]  1  2 NA  1
```

But what I want to have as an output is the different breaks counted in a vector like:

```
c(youth = 1, adult = 2, elder = 1)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why not just use `table(cut(...))` with `...` replaced by data and parameters according to the `cut` function? Eg. `setNames(table(cut(numbers1, c(-Inf, breaks1))), c('youth', 'adult', 'elder'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut already exists, add table

```
> table(cut(numbers1,c(0,breaks1),labels=names(breaks1),right=T,include.lowest=F))
youth adult elder 
    1     2     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```r
binfunc <- function(numbers, breaks){
  rowSums(sapply(numbers, \(x) (x <breaks[order(breaks)]) )) |>
    (\(d) c(d[1], diff(d)))()
}

numbers1 <- c(20, 70, 14, 30)
breaks1 <- c(youth = 18, adult = 40, elder = Inf)

binfunc(numbers1, breaks1)
#> youth adult elder 
#>     1     2     1

numbers2 <- c(20, 70, 14, 30, 10, 10, 25, 40, 11, 55)
breaks2 <- c(youth = 18, adult = 40, elder = Inf, mid = 25)

binfunc(numbers2, breaks2)
#> youth   mid adult elder 
#>     4     1     2     3
```